# Vertical justification and getting rid of extra line segments (in the first cell)

Tags: tables, formatting, vertical-alignment

I am working on a table.

My problem is that the text in the column "Type" for instance is not vertical justified. In addition I have an extra line segment at the bottom of the very first cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|p{3cm}|p{5cm}|}
      \cline{2-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &Type & Criteria \\ \cline{2-3}
        \hline
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{Objective}
            & {Shortest path (global, local) }&   exits in sight range, signs, experience,  \ldots \\ \cline{2-3}
            & {Quickest path}&   jam in sight range, experience,\ldots \\ \cline{2-3}
            &Given path &   directives from signs, personal,\ldots \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{Subjective}
    &Pleasant path &   design, clarity, lighting, experience, emotional state, \\ \cline{2-3}
    &Safest path &   experience, overview, walking in group\ldots \\ \cline{2-3}
    &Known path &  experience, overview, (re) identification of signs,\ldots\\ \hline
  \ldots &\ldots &\ldots \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Examples of path types inside a facility and possible influencing criteria.}
\label{tab:path_types}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please edit your question to clarify what the issue is as I don't see it form the output and the title.  Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages (As @DavidCarlisle has already done for you in this case).

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx, I have made your example into a complete "MWE" example, loading multirow, but could you edit the question to add a question? Just posting some code that runs without error does not give us much of a clue as to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for editing the post (Apologies for not even clarify my problem). My problem is that the text in the column "Type" for instance is not vertical justified. In addition I have an extra line segment at the bottom of the very first cell.  Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For varied single/double horizontal and intersecting/split vertical lines in a `tabular` (or `array`) environment, use the [`hhline` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline). Here's your example, with the modified `\hline\hline`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|p{3cm}|p{5cm}|}
    \cline{2-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Type & Criteria \\ 
    %\hline
    %\hline
    \hhline{-:=:=}
    \multirow{3}{*}{Objective}
      & Shortest path (global, local) & exits in sight range, signs, experience,  \ldots \\ \cline{2-3}
      & Quickest path & jam in sight range, experience, \ldots \\ \cline{2-3}
      & Given path & directives from signs, personal, \ldots \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Subjective}
      & Pleasant path & design, clarity, lighting, experience, emotional state, \\ \cline{2-3}
      & Safest path & experience, overview, walking in group \ldots \\ \cline{2-3}
      & Known path &experience, overview, (re) identification of signs, \ldots\\ \hline
    \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Examples of path types inside a facility and possible influencing criteria.}
  \label{tab:path_types}
\end{table}
\end{document}​
```

The [`hhline` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/hhline.pdf) contains more information on specifying the arguments to `\hhline`.

Note that code-only questions provide little context, even if you feel that the question is posed in the header/title.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any way to vertically center teh values in the column Type for  instance?

Comment: @Kemloh: You can prepend any of `Type` or `Criteria` with `\rule{0pt}{.9\baselineskip}`. This will insert a zero-width rule that stretches above/higher than those entries, pushing the first `\cline` up a little, and making it more centred. For more on horizontal/vertical padding of `tabular` or `array` elements, see [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764).